# How to build a tracking script

Tags: analytics, tracking

I would like to know how to build a tracking solution (similar to what Google Analytics does).
So far I'm able to gather some simple data such as Ip address, location, date, referrer etc..  thanks to a pixel placed on the target website.

I was wondering how to gather more specific and relevant data such as website's users actions, what buttons do they click on, the data they enter in the forms etc.

The idea would be to build a service and provide analytics to websites.

Thank you for your help